# How to make profile2 completely replace or override the core profile?

Tags: 7, views, users, panels

I have installed the [Profile 2 module](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2). I want to make it replace or override the core profile module for the entire website but I don't know how to achieve this. I have searched a lot, but have not found a solution. This is a new website, so I would not need to migrate existing profiles to profile2.

Can this be done using the Panels and Page Manager modules?

Is it a good idea to keep using the core profile module?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing this as profile2 is designed to compliment the core profile module.

The simplest way of explaining this is that the core profile module handles your account while profile2 handles all the extra information not required in order to be a Drupal user.

On a large sports team website that I run we use profile2. When users go their user page they see in order:

- Their picture (a field of the core profile module)
- Their email settings (core profile module)
- A heading titled "Personal Information" (profile2 module)
- All their personal information (First Name, Last Name, DOB, Address, Contact Number) (profile2 module)
- Another heading title "Medical Information" (profile2 module)
- All their medical info (Injuries, Allergies, Medications, Emergency Contact) (profile2 module)

When they go to edit their profile, the main tab is titled "Account" and allows them to change their username, email address, password, email settings, and profile picture. Profile2 adds "Personal" and "Medical" tabs where users go to complete the other two profiles.

Our club contact list gives all users access to the main profile which contains the username, picture, and email address. Only club executives and coaches have access to the personal information profile and only coaches have access to the medical information profile.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. And obviously the user itself has access to his own personal info profile and medical. So what I have understood is that you need profile2 if and only if you want another profile page/type with some extra info. Correct? If you are feeling kind, I need your suggestions.

Comment: I am creating a social networking website. You must have seen profile pages on famous social networks. What do I need to achieve that? and do I have to create the edit page separately or the changes I make to the profile page automatically become visible on the edit page too?

Comment: That is correct. Drupal already allows you to add fields to the built in profile page. Profile 2 allows you to add additional profile pages with more information. The ideal use case is when you want to have information separated by category for example (medical, personal, customer, client, etc)

When you add a field to the profile (or profile2) it will become visible on the edit page as well (if you give the user permissions to edit it). You can also have profile2 pages that the user CANNOT edit

Comment: loads of thanks for taking out time and explaining to me. I know how to add a field, edit with page manager and panels, but is there any guide/tutorial which specifically focuses on profile page or user section so that I can create a perfect profile page. For example: twitter or linkedin profile pages.

Comment: and when the user clicks on "edit", the page becomes editable without going to another page. Is it possible?